# Arrow key effect on android layout button-

Tags: android

I have three layout based buttons. I m developing this project for android stick so user will use keyboard.I want to show selected state when user navigate between buttons using arrow key same like we have in list/grid view. How can I add make button selected when user use keyboard?

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:id="@+id/linear_top_button"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#041F34"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:text="06.56"
        android:textColor="#475B6D"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:text="Day"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:id="@+id/linear_second_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#041F34"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:focusable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:text="06.56"
        android:textColor="#475B6D"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:text="Day"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:id="@+id/linear_third_button"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#041F34"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:text="06.56"
        android:textColor="#475B6D"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:text="Day"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>

_oneButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    _oneButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#163040"));//#163040//#041F34 n
                    _twoButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));
                    _threeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));
                    Log.d("p","1"); //Never called!
                }
            }
      );
    _twoButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    _twoButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#163040"));//#163040//#041F34 n
                    _oneButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));
                    _threeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));
                    Log.d("p","2"); //Never called!
                }
            }
      );
    _threeButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    _threeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#163040"));//#163040//#041F34 n
                    _oneButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));
                    _twoButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));
                    Log.d("p","3"); //Never called!
                }
            }
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by implementing onfocus listener.

```
    _threeButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new   View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            _threeButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#163040"));//#163040//#041F34 n
            _oneButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));
            _twoButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#041F34"));


        }
    });
```